# Extracting a string from a string using xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Sorry for the dumb question, but string handling in xsl 1.0 is not one of my strong points. 
I'm looking for a way of extracting a string held between pseudo html tags.
EG.

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
    This is a string <link>http://www.stackoverflow.com</link> and some more stuff here
</xsl:variable>
```

The idea being to end up with 2 further variables that would contain.

var1 = http://www.stackoverflow.com
and
var2 = This is a string and some more stuff here

Like I say, sorry it's a dim question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="test">
  This is a string <link>http://www.stackoverflow.com</link> and some more stuff here
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vTestNodeset" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='test']"/>

 <xsl:variable name="var1" select="string($vTestNodeset/link)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="var2">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vTestNodeset/text()"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     "<xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>"
============    
     "<xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>"
============    
     "<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($var2)"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced:**

```
     "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
============    
     "
  This is a string  and some more stuff here
 "
============    
     "This is a string and some more stuff here"
```